# AngularJS: Populating checkbox list with two JSON arrays and initially checked some items from one array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my AngularJS application there is a checkbox list. This list represents some interests of a user. The user can select one or more items from the list.
**HTML**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>User Interests</title>
      <script src="../scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../scripts/userinterests.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ng-app="userinterests">
         <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="userinterestsCtrl">
            <div ng-repeat="userinterest in userinterests">
               <input type="checkbox" checkbox-group /> <label>{{userinterest.interestKey}}</label>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
         </form>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

In my javascript file first I get a list from a backend function, this list contains all the interests. If this backend call success then I call another function to get the already selected items from that user, this returns another list which contains the interests which are already selected by the user. Now I have two lists (list of all the interests & list of already selected interests by the user). Now I want to display a checkbox list with all the interests but I want to check the items which are already selected by the customer.

This is my javascript looks like

```
var app = angular.module('userinterests', []);

app.controller('userinterestsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
// Get full interests list
$http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : './test/userInterests',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
}).success(function(response) {
    console.log('response=>' + response);
    $scope.interests_array = [];
    $scope.userinterests = response;
    console.log($scope.userinterests);

    // Get already selected interests
    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : './test/savedInterests',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        params : {
            user_email : localStorage.getItem("user_email")
        }
    }).success(function(response) {
        console.log('response=>' + response);
        $scope.savedinterests = response;
        console.log(response);
    }).error(function(response, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('failure');
    });

}).error(function(response, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("failure");
});

$scope.submit = function() {
    console.log('Submiting...');
    console.log($scope.interests_array.join(", "));

    var user_email = localStorage.getItem("user_email");
    var preferences = "[" + $scope.interests_array.join(", ") + "]";

    console.log('preferences=>' + preferences);

    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : './test/setUserInterests',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        params : {
            user_email : user_email,
            preferences : preferences
        }
    }).success(function(response) {
        console.log('response=>' + response);

    }).error(function(response, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('failure');
    });
};

}).directive(
    "checkboxGroup",
    function() {
        return {
            restrict : "A",
            link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                // Determine initial checked boxes
                if (scope.interests_array.indexOf(scope.userinterest.interestKey) !== -1) {
                    elem[0].checked = true;
                }                   

                // Update array on click
                elem.bind('click', function() {
                    var index = scope.interests_array.indexOf(scope.userinterest.interestKey);
                    // Add if checked
                    if (elem[0].checked) {
                        if (index === -1)
                            scope.interests_array.push(scope.userinterest.interestKey);
                    }
                    // Remove if unchecked
                    else {
                        if (index !== -1)
                            scope.interests_array.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                    // Sort and update DOM display
                    // scope.$apply(scope.array.sort(function(a, b) {
                    // return a - b
                    // }));
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

**sample data**

```
        $scope.userinterests = [{
        "key": "test1",
        "score": 1.0
      }, {
        "key": "test2",
        "score": 1.0
      }, {
        "key": "test3",
        "score": 1.0
      }, {
        "key": "test4",
        "score": 1.0
      }, {
        "key": "test5",
        "score": 1.0
      }, {
        "key": "test6",
        "score": 1.0
      }, {
        "key": "test7",
        "score": 1.0
      }, {
        "key": "test8",
        "score": 1.0
      }, {
        "key": "test9",
        "score": 1.0
      }, {
        "key": "test10",
        "score": 1.0
      }, {
        "key": "test11",
        "score": 1.0
      }];

      var selectedInterests = [{
        "key": "test1",
        "score": 1.0
      }, {
        "key": "test2",
        "score": 1.0
      }, {
        "key": "test3",
        "score": 1.0
      }];
```

I would be much appreciates if anyone could be so kind enough to help me to achieve this.

Thank You

Comment: simply check while preparing userinterest.interestKey if savedInterests contain value that are available in userInterests then mark this as checked

Comment: loop through userInterests and check for each element using .contains method. if its true that push some flag in that element.

Comment: create snippet of fiddle. i will work on it

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. I already flag the question for moderator attention.

Comment: Why did you edit my question? Please understand my situation

Comment: You realise that the contents of the post are still visible in the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36277065/revisions) right?

Comment: Yeah. That's why I try to delete permanently. I already flag the question for moderator attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create an extra property of `selected` in the `userInterests` array on runtime like.

```
userInterests.forEach(function(item){
   savedInterests.forEach(function(savedItem){
      if(savedItem.interestKey === item.interestKey){
         item.selected = true;
      }
   })
})
```

Then in your template just use

```
<div ng-app="userinterests">
         <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="userinterestsCtrl">
            <div ng-repeat="userinterest in userinterests">
               <input type="checkbox" checkbox-group ng-model="userinterest.selected" /> <label{{userinterest.interestKey}}</label>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
         </form>
      </div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: By using this method in your controller it will automatically create an extra property in the `userInterests` array just in application for your view.

Comment: it will just add a boolean to the selected object. Its not wierd.

Comment: No you are doing it wrong. it will only add a selected property to the object array

Comment: Wait I will create a fiddle for you. :)

Comment: Well if its just the arrays of `userinterests` and `selectedInterests ` then we can edit our answers and remove the item name in the arrays. Is this okay?

Comment: Hi, COuld you plz the working fiddle to sample dummy data.

Comment: Hi, extremely sorry to bothering to you. Could u please change the working fiddle with the sample data ?

Comment: Because I don't have permission to change the fiddle. So that can you please change it with dummy data?

Comment: @Ann18 yeah sure. have deleted my comment and it wont be visible to anyone now. [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/Lt7aP/2546/) is the new fiddle now

Comment: Really appreciate your help mJunaidSalalat. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use $filter to search and then add a key in your user_interest array and based on that key, select/unselect a checkbox.

```
$scope.userinterests = [{
"key": "test1",
"score": 1.0
}, {
"key": "test2",
"score": 1.0
}, {
"key": "test3",
"score": 1.0
}, {
"key": "test4",
"score": 1.0
}, {
"key": "test5",
"score": 1.0
}, {
"key": "test6",
"score": 1.0
}, {
"key": "test7",
"score": 1.0
}, {
"key": "test8",
"score": 1.0
}, {
"key": "test9",
"score": 1.0
}, {
"key": "test10",
"score": 1.0
}, {
"key": "test11",
"score": 1.0
}];

var selectedInterests = [{
"key": "test1",
"score": 1.0
}, {
"key": "test2",
"score": 1.0
}, {
"key": "test3",
"score": 1.0
}];
user_interests.map(function(c,i){
  var found = $filter('filter')(saved_interests, {key: c.key}, true);
  if (found.length) {
      c.active = 1;
      user_interests[i] = c;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this. its simple and easy

```js
var app = angular.module('userinterests', []);

app.controller('userinterestsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.userinterests = [{
"key": "test1",
"score": 1.0
  }, {
"key": "test2",
"score": 1.0
  }, {
"key": "test3",
"score": 1.0
  }, {
"key": "test4",
"score": 1.0
  }, {
"key": "test5",
"score": 1.0
  }, {
"key": "test6",
"score": 1.0
  }, {
"key": "test7",
"score": 1.0
  }, {
"key": "test8",
"score": 1.0
  }, {
"key": "test9",
"score": 1.0
  }, {
"key": "test10",
"score": 1.0
  }, {
"key": "test11",
"score": 1.0
  }];

  var selectedInterests = [{
"key": "test1",
"score": 1.0
  }, {
"key": "test2",
"score": 1.0
  }, {
"key": "test3",
"score": 1.0
  }];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.userinterests.length; i++) {
    if (JSON.stringify(selectedInterests).indexOf(JSON.stringify($scope.userinterests[i])) > 0) {
      $scope.userinterests[i]['active'] = true;
    } 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="userinterests">
  <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="userinterestsCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="userinterest in userinterests">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model='userinterest.active'/>
      <label>{{userinterest.key}}</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    <pre>{{selectedInterests | json}}</pre>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use just one view model object for this, which had an extra 'selected' property, and bind the checkbox to this property using ng-model.

So basically you would create a new object that looked like the response to userinterests, but had a 'selected' boolean property for each interest. You can use Array.map to create this new array.

You could then use ngRepeat to iterate over the new array, creating a checkbox for each entry, which is bound to to the 'selected' property.

When you writing to the server, you can use Array.filter to produce a new array containing only the selected entries, like the response from savedinterests you mention.